# Determine which users actually use Office

Tags: microsoft-office, domain

We have Office installed in our company's computers, which of course are in a domain.

We are up for license renewal, and want to know which users really use Office, so we save some money by only buying licenses for people that actually use it.

We don't have System Center, which I am told has some kind of auditing tool to do that, so I want to know if there is a way to get this information on all domain machines, either with windows /active directory, built-in tools, or with a free tool.

Specifically, what I expect the tool to do is something like this:

```
Machine #1:
  winword.exe: 5 times last month
  excel.exe:   not run last month
  powerpoint.exe: 20 times last month
Machine #2:
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: We don't do software recomendations here at Superuser.  There is no built-in tool that could do this.  If you know System Center would work why can't you use that beyond that fact "you don't have it" it does exaclty what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, we wouldn't do recommendations of this sort, but I can think of 2 possibilities for you:

1)System Centre - I know you don't have it - but you can trial it, get the data and then uninstall it.

2) Schedule Task GPO.  I once was asked to monitor software usage with a limited budget.  I did this by building an SQL database (although text files or another DB format would work.  I then built a VBS which checked for the existance of an application (winword.exe is word, excel.exe is excel etc).  If it detected that windows process, it would connect to the SQL DB and log time/date, machine, user, application. I deployed this script as a scheduled task via GPO to execute every 15 minutes on a given set of machines and a few days and some SQL selects later I had a ballpark of SW usage.

While option 2 is not bullet proof and relies on the user having the apps open when the script runs, most users who are working in outlook email or on a word doc/spreadsheet will have it open for 15 mins.. especially if its part of their job.

Something along these lines should do you for a starter:
'On error resume next will stop users seeing messages.  Remove while developing

```
On Error Resume Next

'Get Computer Name
Set wshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Network" )
strComputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName
WScript.Echo strComputerName

'Get User Name
strUserName =  wshNetwork.UserName
WScript.Echo strUserName

sComputerName = "."
'Connect to local machine and get all process names
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputerName & "\root\cimv2")
sQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"
Set objItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(sQuery)
'For Each Process Name
For Each objItem In objItems
    'If name is winword or excel.exe (upper case to avoid possible case issues)
    if UCase(objItem.Name) = "WINWORD.EXE" or UCase(objItem.Name) = "EXCEL.EXE" Then
        'connect to SQL
        set con = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
        con.open "Provider=sqloledb;Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DBNAME;User Id=sa;Password=PASSWORDHERE;"
        'Construct insert statement
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblSoftwareAudit VALUES ('" & strComputerName & "', '" & strUserName & "', '" & objItem.Name & "', '" & FormatDateTime(Now) & "')"
        'insert SQL statement
        set rst = con.execute(sSQL)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am now using a modified version of this script. The changes i did were to write "none" on the database if the user doesn't have anything open. Also i fixed a bug regarding the date, since FormatDateTime(Now) returned month-date-year and confused our database since we use day-month-year. I used standard iso year-month-day

Comment: Fantastic, as long as it did what was required.